# Lines to polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, line

I have created a line. Then, I want to create a polygon from my line. I used the `Vector`->`Geometry Tools`->`Lines to polygon` and a little problem happened (look at the pics, I circled it with a red color):

[image]

Why did this happen? I have no line on the polygon where I circled red. I do not want that line on the polygon. I'm using QGIS 2.18.5.

Comment: @Lassus - SAGA also has a `Convert lines to polygons` tool which you could try using. You can access it from the _Processing Toolbox_ :)

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure that the lines are snapped correctly. You can set the snapping option from `Settings -> Snapping option` and select `Snap to` `To vertex and segment`, and set the `tolerance to 10 pixels`.

[image]

Then, if the lines are not connected (split), you need to use merge tool [image] to merge the lines:

[image]

Once it is snapped and merged correctly, you can use `Vector->Geometry Tools->Lines to polygon` and it will create a polygon correctly.

[image]

Comment: I tried it but I think it snaps each other.
Here is my line: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sa2xld1gojeeqgm/dios.rar?dl=0

Comment: I had too much points on. Now it is working for me. THANKS